# Google Script post to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

Did anyone used google scripts to post a message to a facebook profile?

I found this code but can't find a way to get the `graph id`...

```
function updateStatus(){
    var myId="";
    var myAppAccess_token="APP-ID|APP-SECRET";
    var graphUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/"+myId+"/feed";
    var theDate=new Date().toString();
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(graphUrl,{method:"post",payload:{
        message:"foo\n" + theDate,
        access_token:myAppAccess_token
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: you cannot just post with an app access token, please read the docs about different types of access tokens.

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/